# Getting npm install issues when build angular2 source

Tags: npm, angular, npm-install

I want to build angular2 source on my windows 8.1 x64 dev PC.
Node version `5.1.0`
Npm version `3.3.12`

- 1)  cloned the repo - OK
- 2) run `bower install` - OK
- 3) run `npm install` - Errors:

  `npm ERR! tar.unpack unzip error C:\Windows\Temp\npm-11016-2e7afc52\registry.npmj
  s.org\fsevents\-\fsevents-1.0.2.tgz
  npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Windows\Temp\npm-11016-2e7afc52\registry.npmj
  s.org\fsevents\-\fsevents-1.0.2.tgz
  npm ERR! tar.unpack unzip error C:\Windows\Temp\npm-11016-2e7afc52\registry.npmj
  s.org\firefox-profile\-\firefox-profile-0.3.9.tgz
  npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Windows\Temp\npm-11016-2e7afc52\registry.npmj
  s.org\firefox-profile\-\firefox-profile-0.3.9.tgz`

Do you have any ideas how can I fix that?

I tried to cleanup the cache and also make sure that it is actually did by lookin in to `npm cache` folder `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`. Also I was trying to reclone the repo an run a precess again multipe times but `npm install` just continue to throw the same exeptions again and again

Comment: What's npm and node versions?

Comment: Did you [clean the cache](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5133)?

Comment: @eric-martinez just updated the details

Comment: are you running CMD as an administrator (right-click -> run as administrator)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process

- Create `C:\Windows\Temp\` if it does not exist
- Create a dummy folder within `C:\Windows\Temp\` if it does exist
- Run `npm config ls -l`

> Temporary files are stored by default in the folder specified by the tmp config, which defaults to the TMPDIR, TMP, or TEMP environment variables, or /tmp on Unix and c:\windows\temp on Windows.
>
> Temp files are given a unique folder under this root for each run of the program, and are deleted upon successful exit.

- Change the `tmp` var to a new path by editing one of the `.npmrc` files:

> The four relevant files are:
>
> per-project config file (/path/to/my/project/.npmrc)
>
> per-user config file (~/.npmrc)
>
> global config file ($PREFIX/etc/npmrc)
>
> npm builtin config file (/path/to/npm/npmrc)

**References**

- [npmrc man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)
- [npm folders: temp files](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#temp-files)